# Is "the number of 1's in a generated ternary sequence" really a suitable loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I'm building a model that outputs ternary sequences. A constraint I have is that the number of `1`s I have in the generated sequence should be small (while other constraints might encourage the number of `1`s to be large). Instinctively, I want a term in my loss function to be the number of `1`s in the sequence I generate.

I implemented this in Pytorch and I don't have any errors. While this loss function makes sense conceptually, how on earth can my model learn from it? What's the gradient of "the number of `1`s in the generated sequence"? Is there something I'm missing, or is autograd more capable than I thought?

Comment: The gradient of the function which counts the number of 1s is zero everywhere where it is defined (which is almost everywhere on the domain). Often it makes more sense to use a smooth relaxation of such objectives. For example, if we want sparsity (minimize number of non-zero elements) then we actually want to minimize the L0-norm. However, because this can't be optimized we instead minimize the L1-norm which is differentiable almost everywhere (and has a subgradient everywhere) and is the "nearest" convex relaxation of the L0-norm.

Comment: @jodag How would you extend this to ternary sequences (where both 1's and 2's contribute to the L1-norm)?